# MS Teams app to display intranet works on mobile client but not on Windows

Tags: microsoft-teams, manifest.json

I've made a really simple Teams app which aims to display our internal company Intranet on a tab within teams.

This works on the mobile version of teams, but does not work on the Windows client. 
Also, using the web client, it throws a error stating 'This content can't be shown in a frame'.

The manifest is as follows...

```
 {
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.5/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
"manifestVersion": "1.5",
"version": "1.0.0",
"id": "72545647f-dd7c-4205-8749-7351561561f2",
"packageName": "<companyname>.teams.intranet.app",
"developer": {
    "name": "John",
    "websiteUrl": "https://www.<WEBSITE_URL>.uk",
    "privacyUrl": "https://randomdomain.co.uk/ps",
    "termsOfUseUrl": "https://randomdomain.co.uk/tou"
},
"icons": {
    "color": "color.png",
    "outline": "outline.png"
},
"name": {
    "short": "Intranet",
    "full": "Intranet"
},
"description": {
    "short": "Bring the functionality of our Intranet into Teams",
    "full": "The <COMPANYNAME> Intranet app will introduce an Intranet tab into teams"
},
"accentColor": "#FFFFFF",
"configurableTabs": [
    {
        "configurationUrl": "https://intranet.<companyname>.uk",
        "canUpdateConfiguration": false,
        "scopes": [
            "team"
        ],
        "supportedSharePointHosts": [
            "sharePointFullPage"
        ]
    }
],
"staticTabs": [
    {
        "entityId": "intranet",
        "name": "intranet",
        "contentUrl": "https://intranet.<companyname>.uk",
        "websiteUrl": "https://intranet.<companyname>.uk",
        "scopes": [
        "personal"
        ]
    }
],
"permissions": [
    "identity",
    "messageTeamMembers"
],
"validDomains": [
    "intranet.<companyname>.uk"
]
```

}

Am I missing something?

Any help greatly appriciated :)

Answer (score 0):

Your tabs needs to allow itself to be iframed.

Please go through this link to see [how tabs work](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/what-are-tabs#how-do-tabs-work).

Comment: I'm not sure why this was down-voted as I think it's correct - not every web page by default will simply "work" as a tab in Teams. @Gousia's link, for instance, states that the tab page must reference the Teams library, and call "microsoftTeams.initialize()", where it states "Doing so will tell Teams to display your page"

Comment: So a little progress has been made on this - the app will show sites such as skynews.com, but will not display content from my companies sharepoint based intranet site.  I believe theres some settings somewhere to allow content to be displayed in an iframe within sharepoint, but cannot find this - anyone seen this before?

Comment: @bhargav have you seen that?